# Expand width of paper-dropdown-menu content?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

By default, a `max-width` specification constrains the content of the dropdown menu. If you use a tool like the Chrome developer suite to examine the dropdown upon expansion, you will notice a `max-width` specification on the child of the div with ID `contentWrapper`.

See [examples](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu) in polymer docs.

How can we change this max width to say something bigger? It seems like the content can't be wider than the selector in its collapsed state.

Comment: Basically, I couldn't find a mixin for that element.

Comment: It seems you can style `.dropdown-content { width: 500px; }`, but the dropdown content's `left` is dynamically set, so it appears off. Setting the `left` to `inherit` *after* it opens would fix it. CSS doesn't help there as it's in the Shadow DOM of `paper-dropdown-menu > paper-menu-button > iron-dropdown`. You might be able to observe the `<paper-dropdown-menu>.opened` property, and imperatively set the `iron-dropdown`'s `left`. Hacky, but maybe helpful.